# How to read a PHP string as HTML

Tags: php, html, escaping, html-entities, htmlspecialchars

I have a PHP file I'm using to generate an HTML file. This is the process:

```
$document = new DomDocument;
$document->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$document->validateOnParse = true;
$document->loadHTML(file_get_contents("http://www.example.com/base.html"));

$testNode = $document->createElement("div", "This is a <br> test");
$document->appendChild($testNode);

$document->saveHTMLFile("output.html");
```

This spits out an HTML file containing the following element:

```
<div>This is a &lt;br&gt; test</div>
```

That is, the `<br>` tags get converted to `&lt;br&gt;` in the actual HTML. I have tried all of these methods to unescape the string:

```
htmlspecialchars("This is a <br> test");

rawurldecode("This is a <br> test");

urldecode("This is a <br> test");

function decodeashtml($str) {
$str = preg_replace("/%u([0-9a-f]{3,4})/i","&#x\\1;",urldecode($str));
return html_entity_decode($str,null,'UTF-8');;
}
decodeashtml("This is a <br> test");
```

but they all produce:

`This is a &lt;br&gt; test`

What else can I do to get HTML tags to appear correctly as HTML?

Comment: You could `str_replace` it? Make an array of all the values you need. Same principle as bbcode

Comment: What is `$document` object?

Comment: @Inurosen `$document = new DomDocument;`

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're using DomDocument?

Comment: @Styphon I'm not sure what an alternative would be. It's been producing the desired results in every other way. Is there a different document type I could try?

Comment: @JeroenBellemans I've already tried a `preg_replace`, but the characters on the PHP side are already correct. They seem to change when being read as HTML.

Comment: I mean, why aren't you just echoing it out? Why do you need to use DomDocument? If I want to add a paragraph to some html I just use `<?php $html = "This is a <br> test"; echo "<p>".$html."</p>"`;

Comment: @Styphon I don't have a base HTML file I can edit - I'm using a PHP file to generate a series of HTML files, using `saveHTMLFile()`. So I can't simply throw some PHP inside an HTML tag.

Comment: @NaftaliBeder Sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. Why don't you update your question with what you're trying to achieve in more detail. Explain what output you want, e.g. a variable containing HTML that you can save to a file.

Comment: @Styphon Interesting, I hadn't heard about the XY problem before. I've edited my question to add the surrounding details, so please check it out.

Comment: I see why you use it now. The solution offered by ceejayoz is probably the best you'll get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found exactly what I'm looking for:

```
$document = new DomDocument;
$document->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$document->validateOnParse = true;
$document->loadHTML(file_get_contents("http://www.example.com/base.html"));

$newDiv = $document->createElement("div");
$fragment = $document->createDocumentFragment();
$fragment->appendXML("<p>I can write<br/>my HTML here.</p>");
$newDiv->appendChild($fragment);

$document->appendChild($newDiv);

$document->saveHTMLFile("output.html");
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

```
<?php echo html_entity_decode("this is <br> test."); ?>
```

Comment: Because I don't want to output the text directly on the page, but rather want to store it in a variable, I don't think I can use `echo`.

Comment: so you can also store this in a php variable, and whenever you want to use then you can.

Answer (score 1):

`<p>This is a <br /> test</p>` is a `p` element containing a text node, a `br` element, and another text node.

To do this properly with PHP's XML writer:

```
$element = $document->createElement('p');

$element->appendChild($document->createTextNode('This is a '));
$element->appendChild($document->createElement('br'));
$element->appendChild($document->createTextNode(' test'));

$document->appendChild($element);
```

Comment: This works, thank you. It's a little more verbose than I was hoping for (I'd hoped to be able to use HEREDOC for multi-line HTML text), so before I accept this as the right answer, I want to check if there's a way to do that instead.